# animation of an object using delta time

Tags: c++, glfw, opengl-3

I am trying to animate a ball movement. I want to start the animation when the user presses space bar.

Right now, the animation is very weird.

```
//global
float delta_time = 0.0f;
float last_frame = 0.0f;

// render loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float current_frame = glfwGetTime();
        delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;
        last_frame = current_frame;

        if (isAnimate)
        {
            delta_time += 1.0f;
        }

        processInput(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // render
        render_scene();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

void render_scene(Shader inShader,
                  float radius)
{
    ...

    float x_pos = 0;
    float y_pos = 0;
    float z_pos = 0;

    x_pos +=  vx * delta_time;
    y_pos +=  vy * delta_time - (g / 2.0f) * delta_time * delta_time;
    z_pos +=  0.0f;

    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos));

    draw_s();

}

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window)
{
    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        if (isAnimate) isAnimate = 0;
        else
        {
            isAnimate = 1;
        }

    }

    if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        isAnimate = 0;
        delta_time = 0.0f;

    }
...
}
```

Comment: It looks more like you're always animating, but adding one second to the frame time when `isAnimate` is true. If you're running at sixty frames per second, your animation time is advancing by more than a minute every second. (Assuming of course that you're measuring velocity and acceleration in units per second.)

Comment: @molbdnilo:It's not intentional.I just want the animation to start when I press the space bar. I tried to remove the `delta_time +=1.0f;` from the `if loop` and instead put the delta_time definition inside the `isAnimate` loop , but still no good animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just "stopping time" when you don't want the animation to run? Something like:

```
float current_frame = glfwGetTime();

if (isAnimate)
    delta_time = current_frame - last_frame;
else
    delta_time = 0;

last_frame = current_frame;
```

Comment: @George even with delta_time set to 0?

Comment: @jackw11111:No, when the screen loads the object doesn't move.When I press space bar , then it moves

Comment: Any other ideas for that? Thanks!

Comment: @George Could you explain a bit more about how it works now, and how you would like it to work?

Comment: I have uploaded a video [here](https://gofile.io/?c=xw6k0W). I want when the user presses space bar to start animating. Right now, it moves weird as you can see

Comment: @George So if you hit the spacebar once the animation starts, but instead of running smooth it stutters back and forth?

Comment: Yes and then it almost stays in one point moving very slightly back and forth.

Comment: @George Your animation movement is determined by `vx, vy, delta_time, and g`, so I would guess that the problem is with (one of) them, or in the structure of `render_scene`. But I don't think it would be a good idea to edit this question too much (it would more or less become a new question), so try to start a new question with this description in it, the code in `render_scene` and code showing where your variables are set - that should also get more eyes on your problem.

Comment: Ok, I just found it! I had `x_pos, y_pos, z_pos` in `render_scene`. I put them in the global scope and it works! Thanks!